# chrome download function dose not pass filename

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a js function that downloads a file from url, for some reason when using chrome, it does not show proper filename. it looks like filename variable does not get passed to chrome.downloads.download function(see screenshot)[image], also, mime type does not work either. I added alert there to verify and it does show correct filename though. Anybody knows how come this happens?

Thanks

```
function downloadDownloader(context) {
                const filename = `download-${tabInfo.carNumber}.sh`;
                const bash = (downloaderType === 'hls' ? bashTemplate4hls : bashTemplate).compile(context);
                const blob = new Blob([bash], {
                    type: 'text/x-shellscript'
                });
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                alert(filename);
                chrome.downloads.download({
                    url,
                    saveAs: true, filename
                });
            }
```

Comment: If you have onDeterminingFilename listener then it's a bug in Chrome and to fix it you need to remove the listener. Otherwise, try a different `type` for blob e.g. `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent so much time on this and eventually I found out that it was another chrome extension causing the issue, to be specific, that extension is called "Aria2c Integration"
Once I disabled it, chrome.downloads.download function works normally.
not sure how it could cause it, but that was it.